# how to add virtual hosts without having to restart apache in bitnami server

Tags: bitnami

I want to restart only `httpd` for example in another server like centos I would do this

```
/etc/init.d/httpd reload
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitnami Engineer here,

You can perform a [graceful restart](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/stopping.html#graceful) of the Apache service by running the following command

```
sudo /opt/bitnami/apache/bin/httpd -f /opt/bitnami/apache/conf/httpd.conf -k graceful
```

> Note: If the /opt/bitnami/apache folder doesn't exist, try using /opt/bitnami/apache2